# Android - how to use Cyrillic letters in left drawerLayout

Tags: android, locale

I want to use cyrillic letters in my left drawerlayout. It should work like a menu. 
I have tried to format a string to cyrillic locale but it does not work, instead it is replaced with ???

```
private String[] drawerTitles;
drawerTitles[0] = String.format(new Locale("bs_#Cyrl"),"1 фыв");
```

Why is that so and what must be changed that it takes the cyrillic letters?

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try define strings at res/values/strings.xml

```
<!-- Nav Drawer Menu Items -->
<string-array name="nav_drawer_items">
    <item >1 фыв</item>
    <item >2 фыв</item>
    <item >3 фыв</item>
    <item >4 фыв</item>
</string-array>
```

and

```
 ....
    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));

    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably, your sources are not unicode files. So try to define your strings in resources.